# How to separate data from getline each time there is a space

Tags: c++

```cpp
int main() {
    ifstream billFile;
    billFile.open("bill.in"); //opening file

    if( billFile.is_open() ){
      string line1;
      
      getline(billFile, line1);

      cout << line1 << endl;
}
```

The `bill.in` file contains:

```
12 100
```

How can I separate `12` and `100` into two different variables?

Comment: If we go ahead and look up the [documentation for `std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), there seems to be a lot of [good functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) which can be [used together](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) to accomplish what you want. Where did you get stuck in your approach here?

Comment: Simple: don’t use `getline`. Use `>>`.

Comment: `stringstream` and `>>` can  read word by word as well if you can't read from the file that way or happen to have a string from some other source.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::istringstream` to parse `line1`:

```
int main()
{
    ifstream billFile("bill.in"); //opening file
    if( billFile.is_open() )
    {
        string line1;
        if( getline(billFile, line1) )
        {
            istringstream iss(line1);
            int value1, value2;
            if( iss >> value1 >> value2 )
                cout << value1 << ' ' << value2 << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, if your file has *only* 1 line, then you can just omit `getline()`, eg:

```
int main()
{
    ifstream billFile("bill.in"); //opening file
    if( billFile.is_open() )
    {
        int value1, value2;
        if( billFile >> value1 >> value2 )
            cout << value1 << ' ' << value2 << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following `split` function to divvy up each line based on some set of delimiters (a space in your case).

```
std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string& str, 
                               std::string delims = " \t") {
    std::vector<std::string> strings;
    size_t start;
    size_t end = 0;
    while ((start = str.find_first_not_of(delims, end)) != std::string::npos) {
        end = str.find_first_of(delims, start);
        strings.push_back(str.substr(start, end - start));
    }
    return strings;
}
```

then you can split each line into a vector of strings:

```
int main() {
    ifstream billFile;
    billFile.open("bill.in"); //opening file
    if( billFile.is_open() ){
      string line;
      getline(billFile, line);
      std::vector<std::string> str = split(line, " ");
      std::string line1 = str[0];
      cout << line1 << endl;
   }
}
```

You use this method to split up strings using any delimiter you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you input file only contains one line and your keyboard is in very poor working order and you really need to minimize keystrokes you can write:

```
int main(){
    int v1, v2;
    if(std::ifstream("bill.in") >> v1 >> v2){
        // here you have valid v1 and v2.
    }
}
```

The `>>` "formatted input" is appropriate here because it is convenient to understand the contents of the text file as numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Function `std::getline()` takes delimitation as claimed in [C++ reference](https://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/). So just use `getline(istream, str, ' ');`.

Modify your codes as

```
int main() {
ifstream billFile;
billFile.open("bill.in"); //opening file

if( billFile.is_open() ){
  string line1;
  
  getline(billFile, line1, ' ');

  cout << line1 << endl;
}
```